# Amazon S3 Set Expires header

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there any way to tell Amazon S3 that all existing and future files in some bucket should have some speicific Expires header?

Comment: Cache-Control:public ,max-age=31536000
For one year, or 86400 for one day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501465/how-to-add-cache-control-in-aws-s3

Answer (score 2):

You can always set policies for buckets, such that they will be applied to all objects added to it. You can use the AWS Policy Generator to create one -- though I'm not sure of the exact syntax for EXPIRES headers. If you find out the right format, please reply!

http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html